# How do I reset query part with knex.js

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I tried to find anything here in [documentation](http://knexjs.org/#changelog) with no success.

What I would like to do is to clone my query builder and reset some query parts like order by or group by. How can I do that ?

It looks like there is no many methods available for this query parts

[image]

And there are clear methods only for selects and where conditions.
How do you do it ?

Example:

```
const qb = knex
  .select('id')
  .from('table')
  .where({ visibility: 'public' })
  // some left joins here
  .groupBy('id')
```

How can I do then something like

```
const new_qb = qb
  .clone()
  // remove group by here
  .clearSelect()
  .count()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset query part there is a way for example:

```
this.qb._clearGrouping('order'); // reset order by
this.qb._clearGrouping('group'); // reset group by
```

and so on.

Comment: These would be welcome additions to knex API if anyone is up to writing PR for these.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the query and add parts to those individual queries.

Like this:

```
//base query
let query = knex('table_name').where({id: 1});

const countQuery = query.clone().count();
const selectQuery = query.clone().select().limit(10).offset(0);

return Promise.all([countQuery, selectQuery]);
```

Comment: this does not answer my question I want to know how to reset query parts from already existing builder

Answer (score 0):

**Latest update:**

There is the option to clear parts of the query (see [documentation](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#clearclauses)).

Example:

```
const userCountPromise = userDataPromise.clone()
const userCount = await userCountPromise.clear('select').clear('group').clear('limit').countDistinct('user.id')
```

Notice that the more specific calls such as *clearSelect* or *clearWhere* are deprecated.